# Proper logging module configuration

Tags: python, logging

I have django project where in settings.py i redefined built-in loggers and add one of my own defined logger. Here is my configuration

```
LOGGING = {
     'version': 1,                                            
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
          'console': {
               'level': 'INFO',                                           
               'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
          },                                                          
         'null': {
               'class':'logging.NullHandler',
         }, 
         #My own handler to write   
         #logger's output here i want to 
         #write output of my own logger                                                       
         'file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',                            
            'level': 'DEBUG',                                           
            'filename':'/var/log/django/log.1',
        },
     },                                                          
    'loggers': {
        #django built-in logger
        'django': {
               'handlers':['console','file'],
         },
       #django built-in logger                                       
       'django.request': {
              'handlers': ['file'],
              'level': 'ERROR',                                            
              'propagate': False,
       },
      #django buil-in logger                                                
      'django.security': {
            'handlers': ['file'],                                        
            'level': 'ERROR',                                            
            'propagate':False,
      },
      #django built-in logger
      'py.warnings': {
            'handlers':['console','file'],
       },      
     #my own logger
     #output should write to file                                                
     'logger_test':{
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers':['file'], 
     },
  }
}
```

Than in one of my testing view i initiate my own logger `logger_test`

```
import logging
# Create your views here.

logger_test =
logging.getLogger(__name__)                                                                               
def index_page_view(request):
       logger_test.info("Info Test")                                
       loger_test.debug("Test debug")                               
       return render(request,'main/base.html',{})
```

index_page_view responsible for opening main page http://127.0.0.1:8000 but specified by `logger_test` message

```
logger_test.info("Info Test")                                
loger_test.debug("Test debug")
```

Didn't write anything in filename which i specified in file handler in settings.py in code above

```
  'file': {
       'class': 'logging.FileHandler',                            
       'level': 'DEBUG',                                           
       'filename':'/var/log/django/log
    }
```

In file `/var/log/django/log` was wrote the following

```
 Invalid  HTTP_HOST  header: 
 'httpheader.net'. You may need to add
 'httpheader.net' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.      
  Invalid  HTTP_HOST  header:
 '/home/isli/projects/forecast/  
 forecast.sock:'.  The  domain  name
 provided is  not  valid  according  to     
 RFC  1034/1035
```

What i am doing wrong ??

Comment: Are you saying that your "Test debug" message wasn't written to the file or that nothing at all was written to the file?

Comment: @FiddleStix I am saying that test debug didn't wrote to file. In file itself have message i will edit my question to better understanding

Comment: My guess would be that 'logger_test' isn't the name of your module so your settings aren't applying to it.  Find out what \_\_name\_\_ resolves to, it is probably myapp.something.test_logger.

Comment: @FiddleStix i edited question

Comment: @FiddleStix of course logger_test isn't logger name. Is my logger name is what defined in `getLogger(__name__)`